# How to find out when memcached's cache item is created?

Tags: time, memcached, refresh, flush, membase

I notice some of the cache items seem to be flushed/refreshed earlier than expected in my application. There could be some logical error in my app. So during debugging, I think it would be great if there is some way that I could find out when a particular cache content (based on its key) is created/refreshed/flushed. Does anybody know how to do this?

I use this membase java library http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/downloads/detail?name=memcached-2.5.jar&can=2&q=

Thanks

PS: I do have access to my server, so even if they are in the logs somewhere, I do have the permission to retrieve them, just need to know where to retrieve them from :-)

Answer (score 0):

If all of your memcache code goes through your own set of methods then you can, of course, keep track of sets/refreshes but there is no way to know about evictions in memcache. They are not logged or reported. The only way to know is to check the key to see if there is a value.